# En wordpress, mediante un botón quiero enviar al pulsarlo a una url que contiene un parametro que es el login del usuario

Tags: wordpress, url

He creado un botón que solo contiene la url de destino con el parámetro del user_login que esta conectado en ese momento, pero no me lo envía con el contenido del parámetro, sino que me lo envía como texto
url **[http://ejemplo.com?id_origen=1:[user_login]](http://ejemplo.com?id_origen=1:%5Buser_login%5D)**
si el [user login] conectado en ese momento es un numero, 100 por ejemplo debería mandar
url **http://ejemplo.com?id_origen=1:100**
pero me lo manda como texto.
url **http://ejemplo.com?id_origen=1:user_login**

Comment: Pero cual es el problema, estas haciendo echo de una variable, un shortcode o como agregas el "user_login"

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: estoy empleando un shortcode   add_shortcode ('usuario', function () {
        $usuario = get_userdata (get_current_user_id());
        return $usuario->user_login;
});